# Does anyone have a suggestion for a hard Drive search tool, that can use a file (List) of terms to search on?

Tags: findinfiles

I need to search my drive for about 200 passwords that could possibly be on my drive. Doing this one at a time is time consuming. I would like to find a tool that can accept a file, or a list of terms to incrementally search on.

Comment: Many operating systems have built-in tools for searching inside files.  What operating system are you using?

Comment: I have found tools that allow multiple File Types to search files, but so far, not one that accepts a list of terms, (say in a file), to incrementally search IN the files for the search words.  (In my case, its a list of passwords, which I need to certify, are not on my hard drive).  Its quite a large list, and  doing them one at a time is mind numbing.

Comment: The tool `grep` on unix-like systems is capable of doing exactly what you described (searching inside files for terms listed in another file).  That is why I asked what operating system you are using.

Comment: My Apologies, I am using Windows 7 at work.

Comment: Are you allowed to install software?  http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/grep.htm could do what you need.

Comment: With no doubt, if you are looking for a tool - Agent Ransack. Its free, no ad ware, and multithreaded (no background indexing).  I cant live without this tool.

Answer (score 0):

Try using grep for Windows:

http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/grep.htm

The command-line argument `--file=<file>` tells grep to look inside `<file>` for the strings to match.  Full documentation [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html).

Comment: Thank you!  I have been pounding Google for hours... didnt find that one.

Comment: The best way to say "thank you" here is to mark my answer as the accepted answer (click the checkmark).  And you're welcome.